# paramiko - Transfer huge files failing

Tags: python, paramiko

Paramiko was able to transfer small files with no issues. But when I try with huge files, it is not returning any error message, but the transfer is not happening. I have implemented this and it is going success for any small files. Any file size in few Mbs is failing.

```
t = paramiko.Transport(host, port)
t.connect(None, username, password, gss_host=socket.getfqdn(host))
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
if target_dir != None:
    if not rexists(sftp, target_dir):
        sftp.mkdir(file_target, mode=755)
    if not target_dir.endswith('/'):
        target_dir = target_dir + '/'
    print 'Pasting source file %r ' % file_src
    sftp.put(file_src, target_dir + file_target)
```

I am not finding any options to set timeout or filesize limits in sftp.put call. is there anyway I can specify these settings

Thank you in Advance

Comment: What's `target_dir` and `rexists`? Please provide a [mcve].